# I need to be able to move the player's head to anywhere on the screen that the mouse is clicked

Tags: processing

```java
//this is ender's game
float r = 100;
float g = 150;
float b = 200;
float a = 200;
float f = 100;

float diam = 20;
float dim = 70;

float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float z = 20;

int t = 100;
int s = 100;
int w = 60;
int h = 60;
int eyeSize = 16;
int speed = 1;


void setup() {
  size(480, 270);
  background(239, 172, 238);
}

void draw() {


  // Draw player's head
  fill(255);
  ellipse(t,s-h/2,w,h);

  // Draw player's eyes
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-w/3+1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);
  ellipse(x+w/3-1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);







  // draw the rocks and wall 
  stroke(0);
  //person
    fill(r, f, b, a);
  rect(x+(1.5*x), (y-(.05*z)), dim, diam);


  // draw ellipses
  fill(r, f, b, a);
  ellipse(x, y+(x/2), diam, diam);



    fill(r, g, f, a);
  ellipse(x+(3*x), y+(.5*x), diam, diam);



  fill (f, g, b, a);
  ellipse(x+(2*x), y+y, diam, diam);


  fill(r,f, f, f);
  ellipse(x+y, y+y, diam, diam);






}
```

I need to be able to move the player's head to anywhere on the screen that the mouse is clicked.  I also need to make sure the player stops when it hits a rock or the wall.

I am just confused on how to use mousePressed or which function I should use to make this happen?

Comment: Shameless self promotion: I've written a tutorial on getting user input in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). Also see George's great answer!

Answer (score 0):

mousePressed() is pretty straight forward to use.
Similar to how you already use `setup()` and `draw()`.

Here's a minimal example that changes the background color to a different shade of gray when the mouse is pressed:

```
void setup(){
}
void draw(){
}
void mousePressed(){
  background(random(255));
}
```

Note that there's a predefined variable also called `mousePressed`.
Depending where you use this in your code it may have a different effect.
For example, here's how using `mousePressed` in `draw()` behaves in comparison to the above example:

```
void setup(){
}
void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
    background(random(255));
  }
}
```

Depending on what you have in mind for your sketch you may choose `mousePressed()` over `mousePressed` or the other way around.

Here's a minimal sketch that changes the x,y position for drawing the player when the mouse is pressed:

```
float r = 100;
float g = 150;
float b = 200;
float a = 200;
float f = 100;

float diam = 20;
float dim = 70;

float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float z = 20;

int t = 100;
int s = 100;
int w = 60;
int h = 60;
int eyeSize = 16;
int speed = 1;


void setup() {
  size(480, 270);

}

void draw() {
  //clear every frame
  background(239, 172, 238);

  // Draw player's head
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y,w,h);

  // Draw player's eyes
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-w/3+1,y,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);
  ellipse(x+w/3-1,y,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);

}

void mousePressed(){
  x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
}
```

This isn't moving as much as jumping from one position to another.
If you use the `mousePressed` variable instead of the function you will get dragging.

It might be fun have a look at [easing](https://processing.org/examples/easing.html) to gradually move your character towards the target position.